# Unable to pull image from a private Docker registry with Let's Encrypt certificate in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, lets-encrypt, docker-registry

I have set up a private Docker registry on my Kubernetes cluster (k3s) running on a Raspberry Pi 4. I have secured the registry with a Let's Encrypt certificate. However, when trying to deploy an application in Kubernetes that uses an image from this private registry, I am encountering an error related to the certificate.

```
Failed to pull image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.42.50:5000/v2/dev-backend/manifests/latest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have created a Certificate resource in the "docker" namespace and successfully obtained a certificate from Let's Encrypt. The certificate request and its corresponding certificate can be seen with the following commands:

```
root@atlas00:~# kubectl get certificaterequests -n docker
NAME                        APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER             REQUESTOR                                         AGE
docker-registry-tls-hhm6j   True                True    letsencrypt-prod   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   7h17m

root@atlas00:~# kubectl get certificates -n docker
NAME                  READY   SECRET                AGE
docker-registry-tls   True    docker-registry-tls   7h17m
```

The registry is using the Let's Encrypt certificate correctly, and I have even added the Let's Encrypt root certificate (ISRG Root X1) to the trusted certificate store for the container runtime (Docker) on each node of my cluster.

Here is my deployment YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-backend
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dev-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dev-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dev-backend
        image: 192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dev-backend-storage
          mountPath: /app/data
      volumes:
      - name: dev-backend-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dev-backend-pvc
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-registry-config
```

I have created a Kubernetes secret (docker-registry-config) containing the necessary credentials for accessing the private registry.

Despite these configurations, Kubernetes still reports the certificate as signed by an unknown authority. How can I ensure that Kubernetes trusts the Let's Encrypt certificate and successfully pulls the image from my private registry? Or is there a certificate authority that Kubernetes trusts out of the box? I'd like to avoid using an 'insecure-registry' approach.  Please let me know if there is any additional detail I should include. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the registry uses the certificate?

Comment: @Thomas You were right.  I wasn't using my cert.  I had deleted an old cert and replaced with my lets encrypt cert with the same name.  This confused me.  I'll add a comment below explaining my process but would like to credit you with answer. If I can do this, please let me know how.

Comment: Please do not cross post: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/unable-to-pull-image-from-a-private-docker-registry-with-lets-encrypt-certifica

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858934/thomas) was correct in the reply above.  I was not using the correct cert.  I had replaced my self signed cert with my let's encrypt cert and didn't change the name and confused myself.  Lessons on getting old and working late into the night.  Anyway here are the steps I used to check this out:

Am I using the right cert?

```
brad@reason:~$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.42.50:5000 -servername registry.dev 2>/dev/null </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

I'm expecting to see `Let's Encrypt` in the `Issuer` string.  I did not.  I saw `Issuer: C = US, ST = Texas, L = McKinney, O = dev, OU = dev, CN = docker-registry`. Ok so now wtf - that isn't my cert that I expected. Is my deployment wrong?  Check the docker-registry deployment.

```
root@atlas00:~# cat docker-registry-deployment.yaml 
:qapiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: docker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry
        image: registry:latest
        env:
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
          value: :5000
        - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY
          value: /var/lib/registry
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
          value: /certs/docker-registry-ca.crt
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
          value: /certs/docker-registry-ca.key
        - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM
          value: "Registry Realm"
        - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH
          value: /auth/htpasswd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: registry
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: registry-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/registry
        - name: certs
          mountPath: /certs
        - name: auth
          mountPath: /auth
      volumes:
      - name: registry-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: docker-registry-pvc
      - name: certs
        secret:
          secretName: docker-registry-tls
          items:
          - key: tls.crt
            path: docker-registry-ca.crt
          - key: tls.key
            path: docker-registry-ca.key
      - name: auth
        secret:
          secretName: docker-registry-auth
```

Well I have correct `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` and `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY` values that reference my `cert` section that tie into what should be my let's encrypt secret that cert-manager made, `docker-registry-tls`. ... Ok so maybe the pod is messed up.  Try deleting it and see if it forms correctly.

```
root@atlas00:~# kubectl delete pod -l app=docker-registry -n docker
pod "docker-registry-56cfd9b878-82gm2" deleted
```

Wait a few seconds for it to get stood up and now I check to see if the `Issuer` has `Let's Encrypt` in it when I probe it again.

```
brad@reason:~$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.42.50:5000 -servername registry.dev 2>/dev/null </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

Well there we go, I see `Issuer: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3` now.  The right cert is being used.  Now for why I'm on this mission... will my web app deploy from my private registry into k3s cluster? Delete the failed pod and try again.  What does the pod description say now?

```
Warning  Failed                  2s (x2 over 15s)  kubelet                  Failed to pull image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.42.50:5000/v2/dev-backend/manifests/latest": x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.42.50 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Previously it was:

```
Warning  Failed                  17s (x3 over 60s)  kubelet                  Failed to pull image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.42.50:5000/dev-backend:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.42.50:5000/v2/dev-backend/manifests/latest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I guess that is a new error, so progress.